# Как почтовые клиенты понимают, что письмо новое?

Tags: php, imap, pop3

Стал интересен вопрос, возьмем к примеру Outlook, либо другой почтовый клиент.

Как почтовый клиент понимает, что письмо новое?

Если проверять по дате последнего письма на стороне почтового сервера через параметр поиска Since или On, то дата может быть любая (хоть из будущего), и, соответственно писем после даты из будущего у нас не будет. Проверять письмо по uid? Писем может быть несколько тысяч, проверка занимает долгое время для перебора всех писем почтового сервера.

Вопрос к тем, кто занимался написанием почтового клиента с сохранением писем на "свой" сервер. Как реализован, либо как можно реализовать получение новых писем с POP3 или IMAP сервера?

Comment: В протоколе IMAP у писем просто есть флаг прочитанности

Comment: Да, верно. Но ведь письмо может быть "уже" прочитано, то есть мы получим только новые письма, которые не прочитаны ни в одном клиенте.

Comment: Не понял вашего комментария, IMAP позволяет получить любые письма с любыми флагами

Comment: Хорошо, если в моем клиенте будет следующая логика: если письмо не прочитано, то я загружаю его в кэш (делаю копию), но если изначально я прочитаю письмо в другом клиенте, то флаг письма изменится и на своем клиенте я его не получаю.

Comment: Клиентом получаются вообще все письма, в не зависимости от того, прочитаны они или нет, этот механизм называется синхронизацией. В IMAP есть [реализация](https://github.com/lefcha/imapfilter) фильтрации в запросе на сервер.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov если получить ВСЕ письма, то никто не будет ждать 30 минут, пока они скачаються.
Хорошо, первая синхронизация, я получил все письма с сервера, а дальше получаю только с флагом "непрочитанное". Но ведь мой клиент не работает 24/7, чтобы перехватить письмо и перед тем как мой клиент его прочитает оно может быть прочитано на другом сервере. Возможно я в чем то ошибаюсь, но я на самом деле не понимаю логики работы данной процедуры.

Comment: @Fox ознакомьтесь с механизмом синхронизации. У каждого сообщения есть дата создания, и для того чтобы синхронизировать два хранилища не обязательно скачивать все сообщения снова, достаточно использовать дату последней синхронизации и сравнивать её с датой создания сообщения. Флаги прочитанности (или нет) идут вместе с почтовым сообщением, и никак в синхронизации не участвуют.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov ну я ведь написал про даты в посте. К примеру из Яндекса у меня есть сообщение в моем почтовом клиенте у которого дата 13.09.2022. То есть оно "из будущего", при чем это письмо от самого же Яндекса и в яндекс.почте оно у меня с корректной датой, а вот в своем клиенте я получаю такую вот дату из-за чего моя дата последнего письма находится "в будущем" и я не получу писем с промежутком даты от даты "последнего" сообщения из-за вот такого вот письма от Яндекс.

Comment: Это время на ВАШЕМ ПК, а не на сервере. Синхронизация в итоге происходит по серверному времени, а не по вашему, локальному, которое при запросе синхронизации конвертируется на сервере в серверное.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov это время письма указанного в ЗАГОЛОВКЕ не по времени ПК, у меня текущая дата и время, а не время будущего.